# Python interpolation error

Tags: python, interpolation

I am trying to use the interpolation method in python (not the built-in one) to get the root of a function given an interval.

I have done the following and don't know where I am going wrong, I have done it with bisection and I though the only difference would be the test point.

x1 and x2 are the two ends of the interval, f is the function and epsilon is the tolerance

```
def interpolation (x1,x2,f,epsilon):
 i = 1
 n = 100
 while i<n:
    m =  (f(x2)- f(x1))/(x2-x1)
    b = f(x2) - m*(x2) 
    p = b
    print (i,p,f(p))
    if f(p) == 0 or b< epsilon:
        print ('The root is at ',p,'after',i,'iterations')
        break
    i+= 1
    if f(x1)*f(p) > 0:           #Equal signs
        x1 = p
    else:
        x2 = p
```

Running this with f = sin(x^2) simply returns 100 iterations oscillating as follows:

## code

```
  (80, 1.3266674970489443, 0.98214554271216425)
  (81, 1.4900968376899661, 0.79633049173817871)
  (82, 1.3266674970489443, 0.98214554271216425)
  (83, 1.4900968376899661, 0.79633049173817871)
```

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `while i<n:` and `i+=1`, you can simply write `for i in range(1, n):`. Also, `p` and `b` are always equal.

Comment: "I have done the following and don't know where I am going wrong". Can you at least tell us what is wrong with the behaviour of the code?

Comment: @user1778543, include the definition of `f` that you're using and the values you passed to `interpolation()` which caused this behavior.

Comment: Your algorithm looks wrong to me. You are assigning `p` to one of the `x` values. But `p` is the return value of `f`. So it's in the wrong domain.

Comment: I added the function. So what should p equal then?

Comment: What are the values of x1 and x2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to solve this using the secant method.  The interpolation method requires three initial values.

I am not quite sure the direction you were going with your code, but I was able to adjust it a bit as following:

```
i = 1
n = 100
while i<n:
    print x1, x2
    m =  (f(x2)- f(x1))/(x2-x1)
    b = f(x2) - m*(x2) 
    p = -b/m #root for this line

    # are we close enough?
    if abs(f(p)) < epsilon:
        print ('The root is at ',p,'after',i,'iterations')
        break
    i+= 1

    x1 = x2
    x2 = p
```

It solved it in 4 iterations based on my starting positions of 1,2:

```
1 2
2 1.52648748495
1.52648748495 1.75820676726
1.75820676726 1.7754676477
('The root is at ', 1.7724406948343991, 'after', 4, 'iterations')
```

Comment: Thank you, I see that I where I went wrong with the p, though I think it is better if you just point out mistakes rather  than give the full answer

Answer (score 0):

In case what you actually want is to solve the problem (instead of developing a solution for exercise), I recommend you to use a ready-made module.

My first choice would be `scipy.optimize.bisect()` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html#scipy.optimize.bisect))

This module has other methods, too, like Newton-Raphson, etc.

Comment: I know but I am trying to do it for an exercise ;)